# Samples exes in the test complete is not closed

Tags: c#, testcomplete

When i run the automation in testcomplete my sample.exe is not closed though i have killed the process for every script and hence the scripts which uses same sample is not run and testcomplete  not responds or in some times it is idle for a long time.May i please know setting in testcomplete which will close the not responding exe and gather information about what went wrong.

Comment: Please give more detail with code

Comment: if ( ! TestedApps["TA_RibbonNumberFormat"]["Close"]() )
        TestedApps["TA_RibbonNumberFormat"]["Terminate"](); whether process filter and freeze diagnostice setting will help me in terminating the exe and how to wach it

Comment: I think that the best way to resolve this is to contact the [SmartBear Customer Care team](http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test Complete gets hanged up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541897/test-complete-gets-hanged-up)